# Apache Spark/Azure Data Lake Storage - Process the file exactly once, tag the file as processed

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have an Azure Data Lake Storage container which acts as a landing area for JSON files to process by Apache Spark.

There are tens of thousands of small (up to a few MB) files there. The Spark code reads these files on a regular basis and performs some transfomations.

I want the files to be read exactly once and the Spark script to be idempotent.
How do I ensure that the files are not read again and again? How do I do it in an efficient manner?

I read the data this way:

```
spark.read.json("/mnt/input_location/*.json")
```

I thought about the following approaches:

1. Create a Delta table with the file names that have already been processed and run the EXCEPT transformation on the input DataFrame
2. Move the processed files to a different location (or rename them).  I would rather not do that. In case I need to reprocess the data, I need to run the rename once again this operation takes a long time.

I hope there is a better way. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Structured Streaming job with checkpointing enabled and a `Trigger.Once`.

The checkpoint files of that job will keep track of the JSON files that were already consumed by the job. In addition, the `Trigger.Once` trigger will make this streaming job as if it was a batch job.

There is a nice article from [Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html) which explain "Why Streaming and RunOnce is Better than Batch".

Your structured streaming job could look like below:

```scala
val checkpointLocation = "/path/to/checkpoints"
val pathToJsonFiles = "/mnt/input_location/"
val streamDF = spark.readStream.format("json").schema(jsonSchema).load(pathToJsonFiles)

val query = streamDF
  .[...] // apply your processing
  .writeStream
  .format("console") // change sink format accordingly
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
  .trigger(Trigger.Once)
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```